# pacemaker config resource for nginx

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker

i'm trying to build cluster by two vm using virtualbox
i follow this tutorial 
http://www.tokiwinter.com/clustering-with-drbd-corosync-and-pacemaker/

and type the command as below

```
[root@node1 data]# crm configure primitive nginx_res ocf:heartbeat:nginx params configfile=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf httpd=/usr/sbin/nginx op monitor interval=60s timout=10s op start timeout=40s op stop timeout=60s
   error: unpack_resources:     Resource start-up disabled since no STONITH resources have been defined
   error: unpack_resources:     Either configure some or disable STONITH with the stonith-enabled option
   error: unpack_resources:     NOTE: Clusters with shared data need STONITH to ensure data integrity
Errors found during check: config not valid
ERROR: ocf:heartbeat:nginx: got no meta-data, does this RA exist?
ERROR: ocf:heartbeat:nginx: got no meta-data, does this RA exist?
ERROR: ocf:heartbeat:nginx: no such resource agent
Do you still want to commit (y/n)?
```

is it normal for these error messages? how can i restore after i press yes? what the command will do?

-----udpate------

```
[root@node2 ~]# crm ra list ocf heartbeat
CTDB            Delay           Dummy           Filesystem      IPaddr
IPaddr2         IPsrcaddr       LVM             MailTo          Route
SendArp         Squid           VirtualDomain   Xinetd          apache
conntrackd      dhcpd           ethmonitor      exportfs        mysql
named           nfsserver       pgsql           postfix         rsyncd
symlink
```

Comment: Linux distro and package version?

Comment: centos 6.3 upgrade to 6.5. <br>
resource-agents-3.9.2-40.el6_5.10.x86_64

Comment: take a look in this bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: you need to be sure, the resource agent is there

```
/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/nginx
```

2: I don't seen nginx in your previous output

3: I'm using Suse 11 Sp2 and I have the nginx installed, without using extra package

```
node01:~ # rpm -qf /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/nginx
resource-agents-3.9.2-0.25.5
```

I know Redhat has removed many resource agents, for more information, you can use the clusterlabs mailing list archive

Comment: any tutorials i can follow to install addtional resource agents?

Comment: i manually create nginx file under /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/ and chmod 755 , will there any problems after?

Comment: https://github.com/ClusterLabs/resource-agents/blob/master/heartbeat/nginx

Comment: i don't see any problems doing that